# nsarray using Key-Value Collection Operators

Tags: ios, key-value-coding

I'm just learning about [Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) and my first example isn't working. How can I fix this?

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], 
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], 
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:100], 
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000], 
                nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [arr valueForKeyPath:@"@min"]);
```

I crash out with:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key min

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your link:

> All the collection operators, with the exception of @count, require a key path to the right of the collection operator.

For this case, use

`[arr valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"];`